# Pop out emails in folder pane only when in reading reply/foward pane?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I have a code that I want to (upon manually running the code) pop out the email in the folder pane to a pop out window. I only want it to do this whenever I am currently drafting a reply/forward.

Right now this code works fine whenever it's in the reply/forward folder pane when I run it. However, when I either run the code again or have the email already popped out in a reply it will open the original email as another pop out window not in a reply or forward.

WHat would I need to do to make sure this code will not open a pop out window of the original email upon already having an email in a pop out for a reply/forward?:

```
Sub PopOutReplyOrForward()

'Not perfected, It needs to not open up the same email if it is already in a Reply/Forward Mode.

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim explorer As Outlook.explorer
    Dim selection As Outlook.selection
    Dim item As Object
    
    ' Get the active Explorer window
    Set explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    
    ' Check if anything is selected
    If Not explorer Is Nothing And explorer.selection.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get the selected item
        Set selection = explorer.selection
        
        ' Loop through selected items
        For Each item In selection
            ' Check if the selected item is a mail item and is a reply or forward
            If TypeOf item Is Outlook.mailItem And (item.ReplyOrForward = olReply Or item.ReplyOrForward = olReplyAll Or item.ReplyOrForward = olForward) Then
                ' Open the item in a new window
                item.GetInspector.Activate
            End If
        Next item
    Else
        ' Inform the user that no appropriate item is selected
        MsgBox "No valid reply or forward email selected!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Per said, goal is to making sure your code doesn't open the same email twice. Maybe couple of constraints (draft) to add see if works,

- Add a loop to check all open *inspectors* and see if any of them have the same *EntryID* as the selected item and are also in Reply/Forward mode.
- If no existing window is found, we proceed to open the item in a new window next.

I quick twisted your snippets, see if it works for you.

```vb
'// 2023.12.11 - Added double checking active/non-active senarios;
'// 2023.12.11 - Added MailItem check;
'//'
Sub PopOutReplyOrForward()

    Dim explorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim selection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim item As Object
    Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim existingWindow As Outlook.Inspector

    Set explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer

    If Not explorer Is Nothing And explorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then

        Set selection = explorer.Selection

        For Each item In selection

            If item.Class = olMail Then

                Set existingWindow = Nothing

                For Each inspector In Application.Inspectors
                    If inspector.CurrentItem.EntryID = item.EntryID Then
                        Set existingWindow = inspector
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next inspector

                If existingWindow Is Nothing Then
                    If Left(item.Subject, 3) = "RE:" Or Left(item.Subject, 3) = "FW:" Then
                        item.Display
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "Email is already open!", vbInformation
                End If

            End If
        Next item
    Else
        MsgBox "No valid email selected!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I integrate this into the code? And do I take any parts out?

Comment: I thought you can just integrate into the 'loop' section and make some minor adj, see my _new_ posted keep the structure and approach, hope it works.

Comment: It looks like you want to ensure that the code only pops out an email for reply or forward if it’s not already opened in a pop-out window. To achieve this, you can add a check to see if the window of the mail item is already active.  Dim inspector As Outlook.Inspector

Comment: @Soki Good called, I now modified the snippets to check both scenarios

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as it ran a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @churchizactiive I can prob see why you occurred 438 at your end... there were bit more thoughts, see my modified script

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the desired result by referencing the active window. If the active window is in the folder pane then it will pop out. If the active window is already popped out it will do nothing:

```
Sub PopOutEmailIfNotAlready()

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim explorer As Outlook.explorer
    Dim selection As Outlook.selection
    Dim item As Object
    
    ' Get the active Explorer window
    Set explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    
    ' Check if anything is selected
    If Not explorer Is Nothing And explorer.selection.Count > 0 Then
        ' Get the selected item
        Set selection = explorer.selection
        
        ' Loop through selected items
        For Each item In selection
            ' Check if the active window is an Inspector
            If Application.ActiveWindow.Class = olInspector Then
                ' If it's an Inspector, do nothing
            Else
                ' If it's an Explorer, open the item in a new window
                item.GetInspector.Activate
            End If
        Next item
        
    Else
        ' Inform the user that no appropriate item is selected
        MsgBox "No valid reply or forward email selected!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```